# how to navigate to login in angular

Tags: angular

In my app-component I verify if the user is logged in (i use tokens). 
If the user is logged he can access the app pages, if not, I want to redirect him to the login page.
For the moment, my app redirects him to the Not Found page.

Also in routing module I have made my routes for several pages
If the user is not logged and tries to access the path 'm-dashboard' will be activated a guard that verifies his role using a switch statement that has default `this.router.navigate([Urls.LOGIN])`
Urls is an external file where I have all my paths for the app.

i've thought that calling GoToLogin() method will solve this, but didn't.
How can I solve this without having to modify the switch's default? I don't want to do that because I have more guards using that.

app-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/m-dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'm-dashboard',
    canActivate: [MGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./m-dashboard/m-dashboard.module').then(m => m.MDashboardModule)
  },
  {
    path:'v-dashboard',
    canActivate: [VGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./v-dashboard/v-dashboard.module').then(m => m.VDashboardModule)
  },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorPageComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

app.component

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {  ngOnInit() {
        StorageHelper.getToken()
          ? this.getUserDetails()
          : this.goToLogin();
      }
     goToLogin() {
        this.loading = false;
        this.router.navigate([Urls.LOGIN]);
        }

  }
```

m-guard

```
 canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
      let customerType = StorageHelper.getCustomerType();
      let userRole = this.userService.computeUserRole(customerType);

      switch(userRole) {
        case UserRoles.M:
          return true;
          break;
        case UserRoles.V:
          this.router.navigate([Urls.V_DASHBOARD]);
          return false;
          break;
        default:
            this.router.navigate([NOT_FOUND]);
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: `this.router.navigate([NOT_FOUND]);` should not be `this.router.navigate([Urls.LOGIN]);`?

Comment: Please can you share the function `this.userService.computeUserRole(customerType)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `canActivate` array can have several guards - you could create another guard just for this task, and test `StorageHelper.getToken()` there (checking it only in AppComponent's `ngOnInit` won't do - the user can simply edit the URL bar). Sth like this:

```
canActivate(): < boolean | URLTree > {
    return StorageHelper.getToken()
        ? true
        : this.router.parseUrl(Urls.LOGIN)
}
```